# Problema Barra de Scroll con dragable

Tags: css, bootstrap

tengo una serie de elementos (img) que se pueden arrastrar (dragables)
y sino caben en el ancho pantalla saco una barra de scroll.

Tengo varios problemas:

1º En las tablets y/o móviles cuando intentas desplazar el elemento con el dedo encima de la img para que se muestren las demás, se activa el draggable por lo que se coge el elemento y no se desplaza el scroll.

2º Necesito además de lo anterior , que reconozca si lo has pulsado , para reproduzca un sonido, o si lo estás intentando arrastrar o si quieres mover y ver los demás elementos:

En resumen 3 cosas:

Reconocer que se pulsa y reproducir el sonido.

Desplazar con el dedo y mover los elementos.

Sin perder lo que tengo " De mover un elemento de la pantalla y ponerlo en otro sitio".

El código:

Aquí es donde está el overflow auto. y dentro el div id="ficha" donde se colocan las img dinámicamente.

```
  <div class="teclado col-md-12" id="teclado" style="width: 100%; overflow-x: auto;  height: 50%; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div id="ficha" class="row"></div>  
  </div>
```

Aquí es la parte del código de ajax para recoger las img y ponerlas en el div id=ficha, también se puede ver la propiedad dragable

```
                    var form = '';
                    form = form + ('<li class="accioform" style="width: 150px; float: left;" draggable="true" id="' + i + '">');
                    form = form + ('<input type="hidden" class="idef" value="' + ob[i].id_accion + '"  id="' + id_accion + '" name="idaccion"/>');
                    form = form + ('<input type="hidden" class="colorcito" value="' + ob[i].color + '"  id="' + id_color + '" name="idcolor"/>');
                    form = form + ('<img name="" class="img-responsive imgf" src="' + ob[i].imagen + '" id="' + id_imagen + '" style="border:4px solid'+ob[i].color+';"/>');
                    form = form + ('<audio id="' + id_sonido + '" src="' + ob[i].sonido + '" class="sound"></audio>');
                    form = form + ('<p style="text-align: center;" name="nombre" id="' + id_nombre + '">' + ob[i].nombre + '</p>');
                    form = form + ('</li>');

                    $("#ficha").append(form);
```

Finalmente pongo la función del dragable:

```
            $(".accioform").draggable({
                drag: function(evt, ui){
                    dragged = {
                            identificador: $(this).find(".idef").val(),
                            img: $(this).find(".imgf").attr('src'),
                            son: $(this).find(".sound").attr('src'),
                            parrafo: $(this).find("p").text(),
                            colorin: $(this).find(".colorcito").val()
                    };
                },
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone",
                revert: true,
                revertDuration: 0,
                containment: "window"
            });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os adjunto una imagen , para que veáis como en ordenadores tuvimos que poner la barra de scroll, pero en las tablets/moviles, la barra es como que es MUY DELGADA casi invisible, la aplicación se está desarrollando para personas con discapacidad cognitiva y de movilidad, por lo que necesito que se puedan desplazar esas imágenes con el dedo , pero al pulsar ya se está dragando, y como se draga no se desplaza el scroll y además quisiera que detectara si lo que si quiere es desplazar o pulsar para que se reproduzca el sonido.

Son los 3 problemas de los que hablé al principio. Muchas gracias, espero que puedan ayudarme , guiarme o cualquier cosa es bien recibida.